# Python Flask, I do not always get full data from checkbox

Tags: python, html, flask, checkbox

Using Flask, I want user to select data through checkbox and collect it in order to use it.

PYTHON:

```
 @app.route('/chbox', methods=['GET','POST'])
 def chbox(): 
    list = ['info1', 'Info2', 'Info3']
    if request.method == "POST":
      list2 = request.form.getlist("liste")
      print(list2)
      return render_template('chbox.html', list=list)
     return render_template('chbox.html', list=list)
```

HTML:

```
    <form method="post" action="/chbox">
    {% for L in list %}
    <p>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="liste" value={{L}}>
                <span>{{L}}</span>
        </label>
    </p>
   </form>
```

'''

It works

But if i spit my items with spaces like :

```
   list = ['info 1', 'Info 2', 'Info 3']
```

my list2 has the numbers after "info" deleted:

```
   list2 = ['info', 'Info', 'Info']
```

Any idea why that happened and how to solve it ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try `value="{{L}}"`

Comment: you should alway use `" "` in HTML

Comment: It was the solution ! thank you guys